# Is there any ways how to prevent SSL Pinning Bypass by using OkHttp3?

Tags: android, okhttp

There are so many articles about circumventing SSL Pinning in Android by using CertificatePinner class in OkHttp3.

https://medium.com/@hojat.sajadinia/bypass-okhttp-certificatepinner-on-android-9a45ad80a58b

https://blog.nviso.eu/2019/04/02/circumventing-ssl-pinning-in-obfuscated-apps-with-okhttp/?fbclid=IwAR3QRvecJl6rlmpN_fpbBGgY2Bvrax3eo-Y7qOf7StYW7_aGsuaIdrr_pQs

https://joncooperworks.medium.com/disabling-okhttps-ssl-pinning-on-android-bd116aa74e05

So my question is, what i should do in preventing bypass SSLPinning by using OkHttp.CertificatePinner ?

What i tried is to obfuscate OkHttp in my project. The OkHttp3 class not found when we reverse the APK file by using ApkTools, but when i use jadx to reverse the APK file, the OkHttp3 doesn't get obfuscated in dex file.

[image: CertificatePinner still found when reverse by using jadx]

Comment: I think nothing can be done, as after decompiling one can still see where the code using `CertificatePinner` is used, starting by guessing what is the obfuscated names of OkHttp3 classes.

Comment: Certificate pinning defends against a man-in-tbe-middle attack. It isn't useful to prevent attackers from decompiling and reverse engineering their own client devices.

Comment: I found this disccussion https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4967. But, i still don't know what i missed in implementing proguard rules. Why OkHttp3 still found in classes.dex ? Is there any ways how to remove or obfuscate OkHttp3 from inside of dex file?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably investigate device attestation to confirm the right app binary is running on a non rooted mobile.  https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation

> The SafetyNet Attestation API is an anti-abuse API that allows app developers to assess the Android device their app is running on. The API should be used as a part of your abuse detection system to help determine whether your servers are interacting with your genuine app running on a genuine Android device.

But I'm not qualified to provide expert advice on this topic.

Comment: I already implement SafetyNet to investigate device root detection and Magisk. I don't have any ideas how SafetyNet works on detect weak SSL Pinning.

Comment: @paulsenjs depends what your objective is. If you want to verify that only unmodified clients are connecting to your server, then it can probably help.  If you want the app binary to verify that it hasn't been tampered with, then probably not.

Comment: yes, agree. SafetyNet is the way how to verify app binary is running on rooted or unrooted mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i had to override mapping.txt manually since proguard rules doesn't works on OkHttp3. Hopefully after i overrode the class name, method name and object name of OkHttp3 would able to prevent man-in-the-middle attackers to bypass certificate pinning by using Okhttp3.CertificatePinner.java